# Como criar função para automatizar uma barra de progresso dinâmica?

Tags: php, funções, progress-bar

Tenho um formulário com alguns "módulos" (módulo = um conjunto de perguntas - não sei se é o termo técnico adequado...), de forma que, dependendo de qual módulo for escolhido, uma certa quantidade de perguntas será inserida no formulário a ser respondido.

E dependendo de quantos módulos foram incluídos, o formulário terá uma certa quantidade de "páginas" (`divs` ocultas, que vão surgindo no lugar da anterior, conforme o usuário avança nas perguntas).

Por exemplo:

> - módulo 1 = 8 páginas - 14 perguntas
> - módulo 2 = 3 páginas - 7 perguntas
> - módulo 3 = 20 páginas - 27 perguntas
> - ...

Então, pensando por enquanto apenas quantidade de páginas, e imaginando apenas uma página para cada módulo para começar a tentativa, fiz algo mais ou menos assim:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
<?php

    if (!$modulo1 && !$modulo2 && $modulo3) {
        echo "  <div class='progress'>
    <div class='progress-bar progress-bar-info' role='progressbar' style='width:30%'>   30%
    </div>
</div>";
    }
    elseif (!$modulo1 && $modulo2 && $modulo3) {
        echo " <div class='progress'>
    <div class='progress-bar progress-bar-info' role='progressbar' style='width:20%'>   20%
    </div>
</div>
    ";
    }
    elseif ($modulo1 && $modulo2 && $modulo3) {
        echo " <div class='progress'>
    <div class='progress-bar progress-bar-info' role='progressbar' style='width:10%'>   10%
    </div>
</div>
    ";
    }
?>
</div>
```

As variáveis `$modulo` são variáveis de sessão booleanas, que informam se o módulo foi escolhido anteriormente (num `form` que cria o formulário das perguntas, onde o usuário escolheu quais módulos...):

```
if (isset($_POST['modulo1'])) {
    $modulo1 = $_POST['modulo1'];
    $_SESSION['modulo1'] = $modulo1;
} else {
    $modulo1 = false;
    $_SESSION['modulo1'] = false;
}
```

Mas como são muitas barras de progresso (até 30, dependendo de quantos módulos...), acho que desse jeito vai ficar bastaaante código repetido, ruim de ler, etc...

Então a pergunta é:

> Qual a melhor forma de criar uma função para automatizar uma barra de progresso dinâmica?

Comment: Então, não entendi @GuilhermeNascimento. Você quer dizer se atualiza no navegador? Se for isso não, é sem Ajax... nem JS... depois que o user escolhe os módulos, ficam gravadas essas variáveis `$modulo`, e à partir delas sei qual a porcentagem que deve aparecer, daí comecei a fazer do jeito acima, meio no braço hehe...

Comment: Variáveis são instâncias temporárias, uma vez atualizada a página elas desaparecem, ou têm o valor modificado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Realmente é o que parece.

Comment: Então @GuilhermeNascimento e Edilson, eu estou usando variáveis de sessão pra armazenar os estados, então depois na hora de renderizar a página (tbm não sei bem se o termo é esse, mas digo na hora que o PHP pega as templates HTML e monta o formulário, uso essas variáveis nas templates pra saber quantas páginas... é a mesma forma que uso pra mudar os links dos botões "Continuar" pra mudar as divs... mas queria fazer isso de uma forma mais simples... não sei se deu pra entender, qualquer coisa de um toque que edito a pergunta... é que achei que ia ficar longa demais se adicionasse todo ...

Comment: código necessário pra entender como o sistema inteiro funciona... As variáveis estão assim: `if (isset($_POST['modulo1'])) {
    $modulo1 = $_POST['modulo1'];
    $_SESSION['modulo1'] = $modulo1;
} else {
    $modulo1 = false;
    $_SESSION['modulo1'] = false;
}
`  @Edilson

Comment: Isso viola o princípios de dinamização na página, sendo que não haverá mudança em tempo real. Em vez de adicionar percentagem a já existente, uma nova será adicionada ao valor total.

Comment: Sim, é dinâmico na medida em que depende da quantidade de módulos escolhidos antes, mas quando monta a página não importa quantas perguntas ou páginas passaram, esta conta "já foi feita", quando os módulos foram selecionado, então o PHP vai criar nas templates com esse montes de `if`... @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Sim @Edilson, não haverá mudança em tempo real, mas se o usuário escolher 2 módulos, com 10 páginas, então será 10% por página, e se for 1 módulo com 5 páginas, será 20% por página. Penso em futuramente fazer um em tempo real, pegando por questão respondida, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer isso, e assim dessa forma já atende o que preciso...  Não entendi o que quis dizer com "viola o princípios de dinamização na página"... poderia esclarecer melhor? Valeu.

Comment: Quando tiver tempo, se ainda não haver uma solução para o problema, eu respondo.

Comment: Então gustavo é que eu e o o @Edilson nos confundimos porque a palavra Modulos é um pouco abstrata e pode significar qualquer coisa, mas esta bem claro agora sim :)

Comment: Ah, legal, valeu! @GuilhermeNascimento Eu até cheguei pensar mesmo se esta palavra não causaria confusão... e como uso ela no sistema para os usuários, acho que até vou reavaliar seu uso. +1

Comment: @gustavox, deixa eu entender melhor. Se eu caio pra fazer um módulo desses, eu só posso passar pro módulo 3 se eu já completei o 1 e 2, certo? Então seria como "um colégio", passando as séries... ou não, a pessoa pode fazer o módulo 4 e 7 ao mesmo tempo, desde que esses módulos não sejam pré-requisitos um do outro? Se for o primeiro caso acho que tenho um código completo na minha cabeça...

Comment: Não é bem isso Henrique... acho até que o título e a descrição da pergunta não estão muitos certos mesmo... Primeiro tem uma página com vários `checkboxes` onde o usuário escolhe quais grupos de perguntas ele quer responder. Então à partir dessa escolha uma página é montada com esses grupos (pode ser até um grupo só). É uma página só, mas todas as perguntas estão em divs ocultas, e quando ele responde uma o botão de continuar abre, e ela avança pra próxima div oculta... [continua]

Comment: O que acontece é que cada grupo tem uma quantidade de perguntas, então dependendo do grupo que for escolhido, haverá uma certa quantidade de divs ocultas, e em cada uma coloquei uma barra de progresso... Dá uma olhada na pergunta (eu dei uma modificada), e veja como estou fazendo sem usar uma função, só com `ifs`... Acho que à partir da sua resposta estou conseguindo aqui uma solução, mas to sem tempo de terminar, se conseguir posto aqui... Mas se vc tem uma ideia pra  outro código eu gostaria muito de ver! :) Valeu!

Comment: Só pra completar, essa barra não é dinâmica no sentido de ser modificada dependendo das perguntas respondidas, mas apenas da escolha no checkbox inicial. Não vai mudar nada ao responder uma pergunta, ou ao clicar no botão de avançar... Então por exemplo, se ele escolheu 2 módulos num total de 20 perguntas (divs ocultas) o avanço na barra seria sempre de 5% em 5%... se fossem dez, seria de 10% em 10%...

Comment: Ops, foi mal, enfiei um `H` no seu nome no primeiro comment... hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oi, gustavox,

Pelo que entendi, você quer que a barra vá se preenchendo antes de enviar as informações (via POST ou GET), então acho que não daria pra fazer em PHP. Faça uma chamada a um arquivo javaScript externo, ou crie a função dentro do HTML mesmo, como preferir. Agora pra cada formulário, você deixa um botão com um onclick="funcao-em-js();", sendo essa a função a que voce vai criar.

Para a função JS atuar sobre a barra, o jeito mais simples (conheço o simples de JS, não espere grandes espetáculos de código de mim kkkk) é colocar a barra sendo uma div com um id qualquer, e lá no JS voce usa document.getElemetById("a_id_escolhida_pra_div_da_barra_de_progresso").

Agora vem a única parte em que o PHP entra. Por exemplo no módulo1, são 8 páginas, você divide a barra em 8 partes... e assim pras outras. Quando a pessoa clicar pra entrar nesses módulos, você envia a informação pra essa página php dizendo qual o módulo $modulo = x. Aí lá no código você põe tipo isso que você fez mesmo, mas acho que com switch fica melhor (no sentido de menos código e mais legível):

```
switch ($modulo){
    case 1:
        $divisoes = 8;
        break;
    case 2:
         $divisoes = 3;
        break;
    //o resto dos casos...
    default:
    //bota uma mensagem de erro, caso a pessoa entre nos módulos de maneira errada, sei lá...
```

Aí você já sabe qual módulo a pessoa acessou. Depois é só fazer um loop pra echo dentro da div que é a barra de progresso:

```
for ($k = 0; $k < $divisoes; $k++) {
   echo "<div class='incompleta'></div>";
}
```

Esse loop dentro da div que é a barra de progresso. Lá no CSS você cria um estilo pra incompleta (display: none;) e uma pra completa. Você pode ao inves de div, usar lista, cria a barra de progresso ao invés de div, uma ul. (CSS abaixo)

```
ul#barra_de_progresso {
   list-style-type: none;
   display: inline;
}
ul#barra_de_progresso li {
   margin: 0;
}
.incompleto {
   background-color: transparent;
}
.completo {
    background-color: a-cor-da-barra-preenchida;
}
```

Agora a questão é, com o JS você tem que alterar a classe da lista, e como não sou expert, eu faria gambiarra... colocaria lá no loop onde sairiam as listas algo como li id="$divisoes+1", e as listas teriam id de 1 até a última divisão. Aí com o botão com o onclick chamando a função, eu criaria uma função com um if dentro de um loop.

```
function funcao_aqui() {
   var p;
   var divisao;
   var max;
//
for (p = 0; p < max; p++) {
   if (a divisao já tem class="completo")
      faz nada
   else 
      muda a classe para completo
      p = max (pra parar o loop)
```

O JS eu teria que ficar pensando mais, com certeza terá gente pra ajudar nessa parte melhor que eu.

Mas espero que tenha dado pra entender a ideia.

Abraço

Comment: Valeu Enrique, to olhando aqui... eu fiz uns comentários na pergunta agora, explicando como pego as variáveis (que são de sessão), e assim pego na template se ela foi setada ou não, e daí se foi, coloco uma %, senão coloco outra... acho que o que estou procurando é justamente uma função com `for` e/ou `switch`... sei lá... ainda sou iniciante em PHP, então vou pensar um pouco aqui hehe... Valeu! +1

Comment: Então, sua resposta me fez perceber que estava mesmo viajando em tentar fazer isso com PHP, já que com JavaScript/jQuery é infinitamente mais simples, e a escolha nos checkboxes na página anterior é irrelevante, já que o JS vai correr o DOM e pegar todos os inputs preenchidos... resultado: além de ser muito mais simples, vai ficar muito mais perfeito (as porcentagens reais), atualizar em tempo real, e só vou ter uma única barra por formulário (e não 30+ rsrs). Como estou usando o Bootstrap, decidi usar este [bootsnip](http://www.bootply.com/106527) como base.